# jQuery vs LinkedIn on .show() : content is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, social-networking, linkedin-api

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HMNQG/4/) code :

HTML:

```
<a id="openDiv" href="javascript:void(0);">Show</a><br /><br />

<div id="control" style="display:none;">
    <div class="linkedin_3">
        <script type="IN/CompanyInsider" data-id="1035" data-modules="innetwork,newhires,jobchanges"></script>
    </div>
</div>    

<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#openDiv").click(function () {
    $("#control").fadeIn();
});
```

Now, opening the div with jQuery's `show`, the LinkedIn module is loaded, but in fact some field are invisible. It works on Chrome, not on Firefox/IE and so on.

Why? Where am I wrong? Tried also with `.show()`, but nothing change...

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle to test that? Btw, you don't need the `href="javascript:void(0);"`, just add a parameter `e` to the click event (`click(function(e) {`) and add `e.preventDefault();` as the first line in the event function.

Comment: There is the jsfiddle! Check in the top!

Comment: Hmm... Works for me in Firefox 3.6...

Comment: Firefox 9.0.1 fails! Also IE7-9 (and to be honest, on IE7 only "sometimes", now always)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, you could replace `display:none` with `visibility:hidden` and change it via jQuery to `visible`, it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/HMNQG/5/

Tested in IE.

Comment: Yeah! Even better, with `height:0; position:relative; overflow:hidden;` and set height:auto/0 with jQuery! Thank you